# Suppose i have 10 millons of fileswhich is of 2 KB in size, so can i store it in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

> > I was asked the question Suppose i have 10 millions of files, which is of 2 KB in size, so can i store it in hdfs? kindly answer to this question.

Comment: Of course you can store..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please update your question with the code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS is meant to handle large files.If you load 2 KB files it will increase overhead and load on the Name Node since it store the Metadata about files.

The block size is the smallest unit of data that a file system can store. If you store a file that's 2kb, it'll take up one block. Once you cross the 64Mb boundry, you need a second block the Number of read operation will be large which will increase read overhead.

Best way is to merge all 2 Kb file into one file and save it on hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can store in HDFS if there is enough memory on the NameNode for all the file metadata. Also, instead of wasting HDFS space by using the default 64 MB block size, you can specify the block size per file so can set to 2 KB if you want. Note that using HDFS like this to store a very large number of small files by reducing the per file blocksize is fine. You will run into problems if running MapReduce computations on a large number of small-sized files.

Also, note that 64 MB is the default block size on HDFS but you are free to set large size (128 MB or 256 MB or larger) and even smaller ones. HDFS has no concept of blocksize per se, it is the underlying native filesystem (typically Linux) that must enforce the blocksize parameter and that is what Linux does behind the scenes.